# positioning of the arrow text

Tags: positioning, tikz-arrows, edge

The edge elements (the text) are not placed correctly on the right side (look at red circles). Is it possible to make them look like a mirror (compare to the left side)?

[image]

Code of my edges:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Sigma demostration draw}
\author{}
\date{February 2021}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\clearpage

\begin{tikzpicture}
 % flecha
 [->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1.7cm,font=\scriptsize]
 % estilo circulo
 \tikzstyle{circulo}=[circle,fill=cyan,draw=none,text=black,draw=cyan!40, fill=cyan!10, very thick, minimum size=6mm]
 % estilo cuadrado
 \tikzstyle{cuadrado}=[rectangle,fill=blue,draw=none,text=black,draw=blue!40, fill=blue!10, very thick, minimum size=6mm]

% G1
\node[cuadrado] (g1_1) {$y_m$};
\node[circulo] (g1_2) [left of=g1_1] {$y_m$};
\node[circulo] (g1_3) [right of=g1_1] {$\neg y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_4) [above left of=g1_2] {$y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_6) [above right of=g1_3] {$\neg y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_8) [above right of=g1_2] {$y_m^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_9) [above left of=g1_3] {$\neg y_m^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_10) [above of=g1_8] {$y_m^1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_11) [above of=g1_9] {$\neg y_m^1$};

\path   
% G1
    (g1_2) edge [below] node {k+1} (g1_1)
        edge [] node {n-1} (g1_4)
        edge [] node {1} (g1_8)
        edge [bend left] node {1} (g1_10)
    (g1_3) edge [below] node {k+1} (g1_1)
        edge [] node {n-1} (g1_6)
        edge [] node {1} (g1_9)
        edge [bend right] node {1} (g1_11);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions is welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, welcome on Tex-SE. You didn't provide a complete [Minimum Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so no one is tempted to answer here. Especially, since your figure is very complex, and you only gave snippet of code for edges, it forces us to write everything else in order to make it compilable. Now to give a bit of an answer, note that you can use `node[right]` instead of just `node` to place your nodes accordingly (multiple options are available).

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answer, i'm just starting in tex-SE too. That works but... I mean, not like a mirror. Pretty similar, but there is a small offset. I've updated the code. Tysm!

Comment: @Joncarre I have edited the relevant part of the code -- have a look at the answer below if it suits the requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

edit the following code

```
\path   
% G1
    (g1_2) edge [below] node {k+1} (g1_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g1_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_8)
        edge [bend left, left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_10)
    (g1_3) edge [below] node {k+1} (g1_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g1_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_11);
```